# Why does the Python Tutorial say that list comprehensions are more flexible than map()?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

In the [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html), it says:

[image]

Why?  I don't see how comprehensions are "more flexible".  It seems to me to be only a difference in syntax.  I can easily do:

```
def my_round(i):
    return str(round(355/113.0, i))

a = map(my_round, range(1, 6))
```

I don't see how `map()` lacks flexibility here.

Can anyone elaborate?

Comment: For one thing, you can easily add a filter with list comprehensions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is *relatively* small, but you have to write a fully-fledged `def` including name or a `lambda` to use nontrivial expressions with `map`, while you can just go and use them in a list comprehension. Also, list comprehensions include filtering while you'd need a seperate `filter` call for that (inefficient and the parens quickly grow beyond what can be managed easily).

Answer (score 6):

List comprehensions can contain nested loops and conditionals:

```
nonzeros = [val for y in rows
                for val in y.cols
                if val != 0]
```

Comment: but I can do nesting just by adding another `map()`,  right?  and I can do conditions with a filter, right?   I don't see the "flexibility" part.

Comment: @Cheeso: A nested `map` turns a list of lists into another list of lists. A nested list comprehension flattens a list of lists into a single list. In C# terms, `map` implements .NET's `Select` while a list comprehension implements `SelectMany`.

Comment: Gabe, thanks for the response. To flatten a list of lists using map, could I just embed the `map()` the lambda or def?  It wouldn't be `map(map(...))`, it would be `map(my_func, ...)` and in my_func I would call maybe map() + reduce().  Which would give me a flat list.  I'm learning, I'll have to try it.

Comment: @Cheeso: You need `reduce`. In other words, to match all the functionality of a list comprehension you need `map`, `filter`, and `reduce`.

Answer (score 1):

```
[ str(round(355/113.0, i)) for i in range(1,12) if prime(i) ]
```

Answer (score 1):

`map` requires you to define `my_round` while the LC does not.

Nobody said the difference was huge ;-)

Comment: You can use a lambda with `map` so you don't need to define a separate function.

Answer (score 0):

As S.Lott implied, list comprehension can do more than `map`.  You need both `itertools.imap` and `itertools.ifilter` to cover what can be done with a comprehension.

```
[ str(round(355/113.0, i)) for i in range(1,12) if prime(i) ]
```

is the same as

```
import itertools
list(
   itertools.imap(
      lambda x: str(round(355/113.0, x)), 
      itertools.ifilter(
         prime,
         range(1,12))))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of your example, it is not map which is providing the flexibility, it is the function definition construct. You could also use that function in a list comprehension, but would not need to.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the difference is subtle but there are cases where list comprehensions have a noticeable advantage in power and readability. I don't think that example from the tutorial was tailor-made to show off the advantages of list comprehensions, but just try writing something like this sucker with map/filter:

```
[i for (i,c) in enumerate('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') if c in 'aeiou']
```

Here's the best I can come up with:

```
map(lambda (i, c): i, filter(lambda (i,c): c in 'aeiou',
    enumerate('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')))
```